# How to request the data of only one cryptocurrency using CoinMarketCap api?

Tags: api, http, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

i know how to request data of many cryptocurrencies using CoinMarketCap api by setting start and limit params but, it is possible to request the data of only one cryptocurrency?  by example bitcoin. I can do it iterating the list of the result that i obtain making a request with start and limit params but i wouldn't like to do it for obvious performance reasons. I just don't find the endpoint to do it in coinmarketcap´s api documentation

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get the price data:

```
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/tools/price-conversion'

parameters = {
'amount':'1',
'symbol':'BTC',
'convert':'USD'
}

headers = {
'Accepts': 'application/json',
'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': CMC_KEY,
}
```

Get your API key: https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what data you want to get.

Bellow two options ***Latest Price*** and ***Metadata***.

## Latest price

```
https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyQuotesLatest
```

### Query Parameters

- `id` :string => one or more comma-separated IDs. These are the CMC IDs Example 1,2.
- `slug` :string => one or more comma-separated slugs. This are the slugs Example: "bitcoin"
- `symbol` :string =>one or more comma-separated symbol. Example: 'BTC,ETC'

You need one of the above three `id`, `slugs`, or `symbols` to make a request. CMC recommends `id`, but the other options work without problem.

#### Optional parameters:

- `convert`    :string
- `convert_id` :string
- `aux`    :string

> `aux`.
> by default it pass a string value of `"num_market_pairs,cmc_rank,date_added,tags,platform,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply,is_active,is_fiat"`
> you can customize the reponse removing some of the attributes.

```py
import os
import requests
import json

BASE_URL = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com'
endpoint = '/v2/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'
url = BASE_URL + endpoint

headers = {
            'Accepts': 'application/json',
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': os.environ['CMC_API'],
        }

params = {
    'id': '1',
    'aux': 'num_market_pairs,cmc_rank,date_added,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply,is_active,is_fiat'
}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url, params=params)

print(response.text)
data = json.loads(response.text)

with open('btc_info.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=6)
```

## Metadata

Metadata like logos, address, Twitter, Reddit related links

### Query Parameters

- `id` :string => one or more comma-separated IDs. These are the CMC IDs.
- `slug` :string => (Alternatively) pass a comma-separated list of cryptocurrency slugs. Example: "bitcoin,ethereum"
- `symbol` :string => (Alternatively) pass one or more comma-separated cryptocurrency symbols. Example: "BTC,ETH".

At least one "id" or "slug" or "symbol" is required for this request.

#### Optional parameters:

- `address`    :string => Contract address, Example: "0xc40af1e4fecfa05ce6bab79dcd8b373d2e436c4e"
- `aux` :string =>  "urls,logo,description,tags,platform,date_added,notice"

```py
import json
import os
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com'
endpoint = '/v2/cryptocurrency/info'
url = BASE_URL + endpoint

headers = {
            'Accepts': 'application/json',
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': os.environ['CMC_API'],
        }

params = {
    'id': '1',
    'aux': 'num_market_pairs,cmc_rank,date_added,max_supply,circulating_supply,total_supply,is_active,is_fiat'
}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url, params=params)

print(response.text)
data = json.loads(response.text)

with open('btc_info.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my own trouble though i'm not sure if it is the best solution. You can request the price of only one cryptocurrency using `v1/tools/price-conversion` endpoint, you just especify in headers the amount and symbol. For more information there is the part of the documentation: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1ToolsPriceconversion